# Trying to post a lead to salesforce and get email copy

Tags: forms, asp-classic, salesforce

We have had a web form on our site for a long time and the results were posted to an ASP page which emailed us the results. Recently we signed up with SalesForce and wanted to use the functionality to submit this data directly to SalesForce. I was able to successfully set this up by posting directly to their URL, but I would still also like to be able to receive an email copy of the data being submitted, just in case there are ever some issues with SalesForce and the data does not make it to the SalesForce system - we would have a backup.

Is there a way I can accomplish this in a simple manner? I am not much of a programmer but can understand a good amount of classic asp.

Comment: you will have to elaborate a little on your situation, in order to get useful answers.  In particular,  what do you mean when you say *I was able to successfully set this up by posting directly to their URL...* ?  are you saying you are now using an ASP-classic page to post results to salesforce.com ?  You said you previously used an ASP page.  Is there an ASP-classic page involved at all, now?  If so can you post a relevant except from that page?  People will need more context around the problem you're trying to solve, before being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems logical to me that you keep your old posting to the ASP page and afterward do the post to SalesForce (or vice versa). like that both emails are sent. To me this way of working seems like a way round, you could just as well send  emails from your form. If you publish that form and ASP page we could take a look at it.